# How can I get cookie/session information so that I can use it with an API?

Tags: session, cookies, go

I'm trying to use this API:

https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API/IEconService

But it basically requires me to have a session/cookies in place already so I need to basically make my `Go` program simulate a connection and `Authenticate` to steam following this format: https://github.com/SteamDatabase/SteamTracking/blob/master/API/ISteamUserAuth.json

But I'm not exactly sure how I can put this all together to get my Go program to `login` so that I can make calls to the logged in portion of the API. Thanks for any help sorry if this isn't very clear, if needing more information just ask.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [`cookiejar`](http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/cookiejar/) to remember cookies.

```
// make a client with a cookie jar
client := &http.Client{Jar:cookiejar.New(nil)}
// post to the auth url
client.Post("...", "application/json", data)
// with the same client make your request 
client.Get("...")
```

Comment: Yes, make all requests through a client with a jar, then login first and access protected stuff afterwards with the same client. If requests fail because of missing/wrong authorization: Do the login again.

Comment: I'll let you know how this turns out once I can do it thanks!